# Firebase Realtime database single value listener triggering many times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to receive data from database in other value listener.

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("FIRST_ROOT")
            .child("FIRST_CHILD")
            .child("CHILD_1")
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : EventListener() {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            val childOfSecondRoot= p0?.value
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("SECOND_ROOT")
                      .child(childOfSecondRoot).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : EventListener() {
                          override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                             doingMyJob(p0?.value)
                    }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

My goal is to run method `doingMyJob` once per change in observed value in reference.

For some reason event listener added as `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is calling method `doMyJob` one more time for each time `reference` trigger instead of run it only once per change. First read from `reference` is OK, but second call `doMyJob` 2 times, third 3 times and so on. After restart app history starts from beginning. Method `doMyJob()` don't change any values in database.

For now I know that parent listener is called incrementaly for each single change in observed value.

Database structure:

`|MAIN_ROOT
 |\FIRST_ROOT
 |  \FIRST_CHILD
 |   |DATA_TO_RECEIVED //reference field - parent listener for many events
 |\SECOND_ROOT
 | \DATA_TO_RECEIVED // root name received in nested listener-as single value
 |  |CHILD_1
 |  |CHILD_2
 |  |CHILD_3`

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a possibility to run listener from listener avoiding incremental call of nested listener?

PS: Sorry for ugly code. I was trying to simplyfy problem as much as it was possible.

Comment: What does `doingMyJob` do, exactly?

Comment: @DougStevenson It ishows dialog, but I don't think that has any meaning.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish here, along with some log lines in the code, and the output of the log that helps us understand what is really going on.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I added database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing. Method `doMyJob` after show dialog launch new fragment (sorry for missed it in my question) and after I close it fragment which add listener in onActivityCreated is relaunched so... val `reference` is assigned again and another listerer is added.

I just love this kind of bugs. Thanks everybody for help.

Answer (score 2):

you're using a `singleEventListener` in your second query, but in your first you're still using a normal event listener that won't go away automatically. So that might be the reason why your code gets called multiple times. So the problem is not that you're **single event listener** is being called multiple times, but the one above might be and everytime it creates a new **single event listener** which in turn call your method multiple times.

```
reference.addValueEventListener(object : EventListener() { //ordinary event listener will be kept running 
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            val childOfSecondRoot= p0?.value
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("SECOND_ROOT")
                      .child(childOfSecondRoot).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : EventListener() {
                          override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                             doingMyJob(p0?.value)
                    }
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: You're right. Parent listener is triggering multiple times. Unfortunatelly this still not resolve my problem. After each change observed value parent listener is calling incrementaly instead once per change. Is this way it should work?

Comment: Also, have you tried replacing the first listener for a single event one? Or do you need it to monitor the node constantly?

Comment: I need it multiply because first call return null.

Comment: Does your second listener alter the data in the reference of your first listener? This might be causing the incremental effect you're seeing :/

Comment: Nope. `doMyJob` is called many times before it starts to do anything.