# Why i am getting Toast "Incorrect Old Password" and "Password Changed" at the same time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity called SettingsActivity. This activity is used to change Login Password.

I'm getting problem in if else ladder. When I click on submit button it Toast "Incorrect Old Password" and "Login Password Changed" at the same time when password is changed.

```
LoginRef.child(currentUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            String oldpassword = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
            String oldPassword = LoginOldPassword.getText().toString();
            String newPassword = LoginNewPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmNewPassword = LoginConfirmNewPassword.getText().toString();

            if(!newPassword.equals(confirmNewPassword)){
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Passwords Not Matching!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(!oldPassword.equals(oldpassword)){
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Incorrect Old Password!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(newPassword.equals(oldPassword)){
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Old Password and New Password Cannot Be Same!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                HashMap loginmap = new HashMap();
                loginmap.put("password",newPassword);
                LoginRef.child(currentUserId).updateChildren(loginmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Login Password Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I don't want Toast "Incorrect Old Password" to be toasted at the same time when "Login Password Changed" is toasted.

Comment: maybe the listener is being called twice? check for that

Comment: thanks for reply. how can i check?? i'm calling ListenerForSingleValueEvent only once when a button is pressed.

Comment: put something like this `Log.d("onChanged","onChanged")` after `if(dataSnapshot.exists())` just to be sure if it is somehow called twice or not....if it is called twice on single change, you have to add some logic to change it

Comment: The code you shared will only show one toast each time it is run. So if you're seeing multiple toasts, it is indeed (as Toushidul said) likely that this code runs multiple times. To verify this, either run the code in a debugger and put a breakpoint on each line that shows a toast, or add the logging that Toushidul mentioned.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933299/firebase-realtime-database-single-value-listener-triggering-many-times. This may be this same problem.